# Exception handling for pandas length mismatch errors

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

When reading a CSV or Excel file into pandas, like:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel(inputfile)
```

I might get a length mismatch error:

```
'An error occurred: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 17 elements, new values have 12 elements'
```

What is the correct exception to handle this error, and from where is it imported?  I don't see it in the library specifications.   Something like:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import errors
from errors import LengthException

try:
     df = pd.read_excel(inputfile)
except LengthException:
    print "Your axes were messed up!"
```

Comment: It's a [ValueError](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#ValueError); not specific to pandas.